# Get Datasets containing just Numbers in Subject Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

We need to fetch all records from our Database containing just numbers in the `Subject` column like `'12345678'` or `'1234567'`.

Now here is what I've tried.

```
Select * From dbo.Lead as L Where L.Subject LIKE '#######'`
```

I would expect that the result of this query is what I want but unfortunately I do not get any result.

Our SQL Server does not support `ISNUMBERIC()` function.

Comment: Is a typo, or did you try `ISNUMERIC()` instead of "ISNUMBERIC" (there's no "B")?

Answer (score 1):

`isnumeric()` (not `isnumBeric()`) is available in SQL Server 2014, and should work for your use case:

```
select * from dbo.Lead where isnumeric(subject) = 1
```

You can also use `try_cast()`, which is available since SQL Server 2012.

```
select * from dbo.Lead where try_cast(subject as int) is not null
```

For values of `subject` that are not integers (ie a sequence of digits), `try_cast()` returns `null`, which you can filter out.

**[Demo on SQL Server 2014 Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=c35ea9df6cf56434bd0c70c4038fdf20)**:

```
with Lead as (
    select 1 id, 'abc' subject 
    union all select 2, '12345678' 
    union all select 3, '1abc'
)
select * from Lead where try_cast(subject as int) is not null;
```

```
id | subject 
-: | :-------
 2 | 12345678
```

Comment: Isnumeric has been around for a LONG time - way before 2012 when try_cast (and the others) was introduced.

Comment: @SMor: ahh yes, you are correct, I just double checked the docs that I originally misread. So this should work for the OP (I modified my answer accordingly)...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this statement. It gives you every entry which contains numbers including decimals.

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColName NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

For a length up to 38 digits, you can use:

```
where try_convert(decimal(38, 0), subject) is not null
```

For arbitrary lengths, you can use:

```
where subject not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

That is, there is no non-digit character.